# Foundation 5 - 1170 grid calculated incorrectly

Tags: html, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I've started learning foundation 5 and I've got app that uses 1170 grid, with 70px columns and 30px gutters (70 * 12 + 30 * 11 = 1170). Altho when i enter default values for my foundation _settings.scss file:

$row-width: rem-calc(1170);
$column-gutter: rem-calc(30);
$total-columns: 12;

But instead of having 70px width columns, single column has width of 97px. Anyone knows how it gets calculated, maybe I'm missing some settings variables? Thanks in advance.

I've figured out that in Chome for example, it generates a 68px column with 15px padding to left and right. Any way to make left and right container padding dissapear?

Comment: Make sure you aren't changing variables in '_settings.scss' and then re-commenting them out and expecting them to return to their original values. You'll need to save and compile the sass at least once with their original values in order to set them back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured my problem out.

It turns out that foundations 1170 grid, is actually a 1200px grid with 15px margins to both sides of every columns. It's actualy good idea considering we want to keep the outside margins  for lower resolutions for frame gutter.

So the solution is to have $row-width set up to 1200.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used foundation but if you want you can create a new class for padding 0 for eg:

```
  .nopadding {
    padding:0;
  }
```

Also I think setting $collapse:true will do the trick.

Comment: Collapse true removes all columns padding, it's all about side paddings that i'd like to change genericaly.

Comment: I added a class for my personal bootstrap project. I too didn't want the left and right padding.